# How to delete a directory automatically when an executable is killed

Tags: bash, files

Quite often, we run an executable that needs to write / read some temporary files. We usually create a temporary directory, run the executable there, and delete the directory when the script is done.

I want to delete the directory even if the executable is killed. I tried to wrap it in:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXX) && cd $dir && rm -rf $dir
/usr/local/bin/my_binary
```

When `my_binary` dies, the last process the kernel will delete the directory, as the script is the last process holding that `inode`; but I can't create any file in the deleted directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXXXXX) && cd $dir && rm -rf $dir
touch file.txt
```

outputs `touch: file.txt: No such file or directory`

The best I could come up with is to delete the temp directory when the process dies, catching the most common signals, and run a cleanup process with cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/d.XXXXXX) && cd "$dir" || exit 99
trap 'rm -rf "$dir"' EXIT
/usr/local/bin/my_binary
```

Is there some simple way to create a really temporary directory that gets deleted automatically when the current binary dies, no matter what?

Comment: beware that you have a small window where `cleanup` may be executed before the mktemp is done. You may want to `unset dir` before setting the trap.

Comment: nice catch, I updated the script to handle this and to handle a failure in mktemp.

Comment: I thought that exit was mandatory. Fixed.

Comment: Your last example mentions cron, but has nothing to do with cron. That last example is also the most fail safe. The only thing it won't handle is SIGKILL.

Comment: I didn't include the cron script that I'm running to keep it succint. It's a find over that pattern to match dirs older than 1 hour and rm them. I want to know if there is any solution that will also cover the sigkill case, or even a brutal shutdown in the middle of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last example is the most fail safe.

```
trap 'rm -rf "$dir"' EXIT
```

This will execute as long as the shell itself is still functional. Basically SIGKILL is the only thing that it won't handle since the shell is forcibly terminated.
*(perhaps SIGSEGV too, didn't try, but it can be caught)*

If you don't leave it up to the shell to clean up after itself, the only other possible alternative is to have the kernel do it. This is not normally a kernel feature, however there is one trick you can do, but it has it's own issues:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /tmp/$$
mount -t tmpfs none /tmp/$$
cd /tmp/$$
umount -l /tmp/$$
rmdir /tmp/$$

do_stuff
```

Basically you create a tmpfs mount, and then lazy unmount it. Once the script is done it'll be removed.
The downside other than being overly complex, is that if the script dies for any reason before the unmount, you've not got a mount laying around.
This also uses tmpfs, which will consume memory. But you could make the process more complex and use a loop filesystem, and remove the file backing it after it's mounted.

---

Ultimately the `trap` is best as far as simplicity and safety, and unless you're script is regularly getting SIGKILLed, I'd stick with it.

Comment: Does it matter if the trap is placed before the `mktemp` or after it?  I would think if the trap is placed just before the `mktemp`, then even if the exit signal were received after the trap and before the `mktemp`, all that would happen is an `rm -rf` command would be run with an empty argument, accomplishing nothing.  But if the trap were after the `mktemp`, there could be a tiny window of a  chance that the temp dir would get left.  Or am I completely off base?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [wait](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9612.html) builtin to wait for a background job to finish:

```
blah &
wait
rm -rf $DIR
```

Comment: But that will be equivalent to `blah; rm -rf $DIR`, right? It has the problem that it will leak $DIR if the script is killed.

Comment: If the child script is killed, the parent script will still be around to clean up after it.  If the parent script is also killed, then yeah, the directory will be left behind.